# IBOutlet nil for custom view xib that is embedded in other xib

Tags: swift, uiview, xib

I am adding a subview(xib) to the view controller. The subview contains other subview(xib).

When the app loads, both the subviews are loaded but , the last child subview has all it IBOutlets as nil.

Below is the simple code with Viewcontroller and two views.
The loadUI() method is printing nil.

Heres the full code. https://github.com/Laxmanraju/SubnibbedView

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let cnatainer = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ContainerView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ContainerView
        self.view.addSubview(cnatainer)
        cnatainer.loadUI()
    }
}

class ContainerView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var detail: DetailOptionView!

    func loadUI(){
        print(detail.imageView). // prints nil
    }
}

class DetailOptionView: UIView {    
    @IBOutlet  weak var imageView: UIImageView!

}
```

Comment: why you add the `@IBOutlet weak var detail: ... ` If you add `detail` with programmatically? Did you check `init(coder)` block?

Comment: yes I did check init(coder), no luck